# vba GoToRecord acGoTo not working

Tags: ms-access, drop-down-menu, ms-access-2007, vba

So the problem that I believe has come up for other people but the solutions that I found are not working yet.

```
Private Sub DROPDOWN_Change()

    Me!FORMAL_CERT_PROCEDURE_TEST_SCRIPTS_THING.SetFocus

    DoCmd.GoToRecord acDataForm, "FORMAL_CERT_PROCEDURE_TEST_SCRIPTS_THING", acGoTo,   Me.DROPDOWN.Value

End Sub
```

I am getting the error "The object 'FORMAL_CERT_PROCEDURE_TEST_SCRIPTS_THING' isn't open."

Comment: Me!FORMAL_CERT_PROCEDURE_TEST_SCRIPTS_THING is a subform

Comment: Awesome! i never thought of it like this and i really appreciate your help, please use this as the answer of this question so i can give you credit!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you leave the *ObjectType* and *ObjectName* options for `DoCmd.GoToRecord` blank, Access uses the active object.  Since your code has just done `SetFocus` on the `FORMAL_CERT_PROCEDURE_TEST_SCRIPTS_THING` subform control, change the `DoCmd.GoToRecord` statement ...

```vb
Private Sub DROPDOWN_Change()
    Me!FORMAL_CERT_PROCEDURE_TEST_SCRIPTS_THING.SetFocus
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acGoTo, Me.DROPDOWN.Value
End Sub
```

As an alternative to this approach, consider whether you can accomplish what you need with the subform control's link master/child fields property.  Perhaps `Me.DROPDOWN` can match a field in the subform's record source?